# Working on 2 features on the fork of an open source project

Tags: git, github, open-source

Well, I'm trying to contribute to an open source project.. I forked the project on github, then I worked on a feature, finished it and pushed.. It's been sitting on the pull request since the maintainer has been away for a week..

So I had to fork my own master to work on the second request, but now I can't create a pull request because this feature (even though it's not related) is built on the commits of my first one..

So how do you guys keep working on the fork of a project without having your pull requests approved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your second feature is not related to the first, why is it built on top of the commits of your first one? Are you modifying your local `master` branch directly instead of creating feature branches?

If you're contributing to an open-source project, you'll probably want to make feature branches off of the local `master` instead of modifying it directly. Then you can use your feature branches to send pull requests against the upstream `master`. If your feature is merged by the maintainer, then you an fetch the newly updated upstream `master` to update your local one.

In the meantime, if your features really are unrelated, then just keep making branches off of the unmodified version of `master`, or use `upstream/master`:

```
git checkout -b feature upstream/master
```

Comment: You're right, my mistake was working off of master to begin with